# Swift asynchronous HTTP calls inside for-loop

Tags: swift, loops, http, asynchronous, alamofire

How should I approach doing async HTTP call inside a for-loop?

I’m using Alamofire’s SessionManager because I need to maintain a session during the iteration of the loop. Due to this, I don’t think I can use the shared session manager `SessionManager.default`.

However, if I were to create a new SessionManager every time, my requests will get cancelled `finished with error - code: -999`. An assumption that I’ve came up with is because the SessionManager is getting released from memory, therefore it is cancelled.

How should I approach this? I feel that it would be better to do synchronous calls instead. But there is no easy way to do synchronous HTTP calls with Alamofire. I don't mind using a different library.

*Some additional info:*

- `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` is set to true in the info.plist.
- My app requires nested api calls, where the completion of the HTTP
  call triggers another one, while still using the same session.

**Controller class**

```
class CheckinController {
    private let sessionManager = SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

    // status is an enum such as .connectionFailed and .success
    func checkin(id: String, password: String, completion: ( (status) -> Void)) {

        self.login(id, password, completion: { (status) in

            self.sessionManager.request(…).responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
                // Check for response, then calls completion
                completion(status)
            })
        })
    }

    func login(id: String, password: String, completion: ( (status) -> Void)) {
        let params = [“id” : id, “pass”, password]
        self.sessionManager.request(LOGINURL, method: .post, parameters: params).responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
            // Check for response, and then calls completion.
            …
            completion(someStatus)
        })
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
for 0..x {
    CheckinController().checkin("someId", "somePassword", completion: { status in
        print(status)
    )}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps look at something like PromiseKit, then you can chain up asynchronous calls. https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit

Comment: Successive web requests give rise to the pyramid of doom, which is why Chris Lattner (Swift's creator) is proposing [`async / await`](https://gist.github.com/lattner/429b9070918248274f25b714dcfc7619) but you would have to wait until at least Swift 5 to use them. PromiseKit is a valid short term solution. You can also look into `DispatchGroup` to hold off execution until a previous web request finishes.

Comment: In short you want multiple request calls and after end of all you want something to perform ?

Comment: @Samah nice! This is what I'm looking for. It would definitely be cleaner than my current pyramid of doom

Comment: @CodeDifferent I see. My current workaround is to create an array of `[CheckinController]` in my ViewController class, and then inside the for-loop when it is created I append it to the array. This solves the problem, proving that it IS indeed being released from memory